# Recibir en PHP, con un debugger data desde una aplicacion android (java) que envia por http

Tags: php, java, android, eclipse, xdebug

Actualmente tengo un servidor escrito en php y una aplicacion java en Android.
Android se conecta con el servidor a traves de http.
Funciona bien y tambien puedo debuggear php recibiendo los parametros desde Android. Estoy usando en php eclipse, que recibe la data desde android y el debugger funciona, breakpoint, etc.

Queria saber si es posible hacer esto mismo con otro IDE distinto de eclipse.
Puedo debuggear usando VIsual Studio Code el php. Pero necesitaria que tal como pasa con Eclipse, pueda recibir los datos directamente desde la aplicacion android a traves de http.

Comment: No se entiende tu pregunta. Por favor expón el problema de forma más clara pulsando en [edit]. Gracias.

Comment: Si tienes bien configurado Eclipse para que ejecute tu servidor PHP con el servidor interno de PHP (o algún otro), debería estar escuchando en un puerto determinado, y desde tu app Android podrías hacer llamadas HTTP sin problemas usando localhost:<puerto>

Comment: Ahi corregi la pregunta , espero que ahora se entienda. Alex, eclipse me funciona perfecto, pero quiero usar otro IDE en vez de eclipse, por ejemplo Visual Studio Code, pero recbiendo los datos desde android (java) en forma directa a traves de llamadas dentro de java con http.

Comment: Otra manera de plantearlo, es poder usar el debugger cuando la llamada al php se hace desde un navegador